# linux + find command with rm -rf

Tags: files, find, timestamps

why the following command removed the tmp directory under /var and how to avoid this?

```
  find /var/tmp -type d   -ctime -1  -exec rm -rf {} \;


pwd
/var/tmp
[root@linux /var/tmp]# find /var/tmp -type d -ctime -1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: /var/tmp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Removing directories (together with their content) that have been last altered today in `/var/tmp` (especially) makes little sense.

Comment: for example - I want to remove dirs/sub dirs that are old then 180 days so I run this find /var/tmp -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +180 -exec rm -rf {} \; , but the first dir under /var/tmp is not old then 180 but the sub dir is old then 180 day

Comment: What's a _180 day old directory_? One that was created 180 days ago? one where no file or directory in it or any of its subdirectories have been modified, linked, unlinked or renamed within the last 180 days? Something else? Checking `-ctime` will **not** do any of that.

Comment: YES sub dir that created 180 day ago ( the sub dir include another sub dir and sub can include files and links )

Comment: Even if that directory is used intensively on a daily/minutely basis? Then that generally can't be done on Linux. Linux stores a birth time on some file systems, but no easy way to retrieve it yet. Could do on FreeBSD or OS/X with `-Btime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first directory `find /var/tmp` finds is `/var/tmp`. If you want to skip that one (and use Gnu `find`) then you can change the command to:

```
find /var/tmp -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime -1  -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

or

```
find /var/tmp -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime -1  -exec rm -rf {} \; -prune
```

Without `-depth` and `-prune` error messages may occur because `rm -rf` deletes subdirectories – which may have already been seen by `find`. `-depth` causes `rm -r` to be called for the subdirectories first. But as it should be enough to run `rm -rf` once for each subtree you can alternatively stop processing the directory contents with `-prune`.

Comment: WHY I GET: find /var/tmp -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime -1  -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: /var/tmp/3: No such file or directory
find: /var/tmp/2: No such file or directory
find: /var/tmp/1: No such file or directory

Comment: under /var/tmp I have dir as 1 and 2 and 3

Comment: @maihabunash You should never use `-exec rm -rf` for testing. Delete that. Then you see in which order the matches occur. You should use `-depth` in order to avoid such error messages.

Comment: is it good idea to put 2>/dev/null after the command in order to ignore errors?

Comment: OK the right solution is find /var/tmp  -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime -1  -exec rm -rf {} \;

Comment: can you please approve this solution --> find /var/tmp  -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime -1  -exec rm -rf {} \;-

Comment: @maihabunash How can I approve a solution? You must decide whether it does what you want... But it seems to me that there is a dash which does not belong there (typo?): `\;-`

Comment: ok the first solution is almost good but the problem is about sub directory for example /var/tmp/dir1/dir2 , so dir2 not deleted - how to tell the command to remove also sub dirs?

Comment: for example - I want to remove dirs that are old then 180 days so I run this find /var/tmp -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +180  -exec rm -rf {} \; , but the first dir under /var/tmp is not old then 180 but the sub dir is old then 180 day

Comment: @maihabunash Does your `-ctime -1` test match `dir1/` or `dir1/dir2`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19110/discussion-between-maihabunash-and-hauke-laging).

Answer (score 0):

Use the logical not operator `!` or `-not` to exclude the path /var/tmp from the results. Note: `-not` is not POSIX compliant.

```
find /var/tmp -type d -ctime -1 ! -path /var/tmp -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Or

```
find /var/tmp -type d -ctime -1 -not -path /var/tmp -exec rm -rf {} \;
```